# add site links to magento template files

Tags: php, magento

What is the best way to add a link to a Magento template file?

At the moment I'm using the below method but I'm wondering if there is a better way which calls a native magento method?

```
<a href="about-us"><?php echo $this->__('About Us'); ?></a>
<a href="checkout/cart">?php echo $this->__('Shopping Bag'); ?></a>
```

I know you can use `<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/test.png');?>" />` to get an image url, is there something similar for links?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to get URL in template file

```
 $this->getUrl('module/controller/action'); //for controller pages 
 $this->getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'some-url-key')); //for cms pages 
 $this->getUrl('module/controller/action', array('_query'=>'a=2&b=5')); //for query params 
 $this->getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'some-url-key', '_query'=>'a=2&b=5')); //for query params
```

Refer this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14443/magento-get-store-url-in-cms-page

Answer (score 0):

You can put the links on the static block and then call that static block in your template file.

In Static block code will be

```
<ul>
<li><a href="{{store direct_url="about-us"}}">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store direct_url="customer-service"}}">Customer Service</a></li>
</ul>
```